# Calculate field data size and store to other field at indexing time ElasticSearch 7.17

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am looking for a way to store the size of a field (bytes) in a new field of a document.

I.e. when a document is created with a field `message` that contains the value `hello`, I want another field `message_size_bytes` written that in this example has the value `5`.

I am aware of the possibilities using `_update_by_query` and `_search` using scripting fields, but I have so much data that I do not want to calculate the sizes while querying but at index time.

Is there a possibility to do this using Elasticsearch 7.17 only? I do not have access to the data before it's passed to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ingest Pipeline with [Script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/script-processor.html).

You can create pipeline using below command:

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/calculate_bytes
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "description": "Calculate bytes of message field",
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
            ctx['message_size_bytes '] = ctx['message'].length();
          """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After creating pipeline, you cna use pipeline name while indexing data like below (same you can use in logstash, java or anyother client as well):

```json
POST 74906877/_doc/1?pipeline=calculate_bytes
{
  "message":"hello"
}
```

**Result:**

```json
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "74906877",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "message": "hello",
          "message_size_bytes ": 5
        }
      }
    ]
```